# how to run the java class file using ant

Tags: ant

I am trying to execute the class file in a jar through ant script. I ran the command through CMD it worked fine
Command is like :-

```
java com.CodeReview -p “<Project Path>”
```

I tried to run this command through the ant script

```
<target name="build">
<java fork="true" failonerror="yes" classname="com.CodeReview">
<arg line="-p"/>
<arg line="D:\Test"/>
</java>
</target>
```

It is giving me error 
build:
     [java] Error: Could not find or load main class com.CodeReview

but through command line it is working and no issue with classpath. Do I need to set classpath in script also.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the **classpath** within your java task:

```
<classpath>
   <pathelement location="yourjar.jar"/>
   <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
 </classpath>
```